# Cloning TFS project setups

Tags: tfs, configuration, project

I have a TFS project setup in a way that works for us but we now have a 2 project to do and would to copy the setup from the first i.e. the overview , board , swim lanes. Is this possible?

the  two project have to stay apart for company reasons so can not be just in one project.

Comment: Please refer to the MSDN:
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/guidance/choose-process

Process template is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to migrate a team project to another place. Currently, there is not a out-of-box feature to achieve this. But this is under plan. You can check [this UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te).

As a workaround, you can consider TFS Integration Toolkit or other 3rd party tools.